# Error starting docker service. "A dependency job for docker.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details."

Tags: docker, kubernetes, systemd, docker-engine, systemd-journald

So, after some minor changes in the docker configuration I tried to restart docker and it resulted in below error message:

`A dependency job for docker.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.`

Kubernetes is also running on the same machine where this docker daemon was running.
Below are the logs of the docker service (output of `journalctl -u docker.service`).

```
May 15 08:56:06 ilcepoc500 systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Application Container Engine...
May 15 08:56:07 ilcepoc500 oci-umount[42741]: umounthook <debug>: 5148572ffa9c: only runs in prestart stage, ignoring
May 15 08:56:07 ilcepoc500 oci-systemd-hook[42824]: systemdhook <debug>: 4676114a4bcd: Skipping as container command is /fission-bundle, not init or systemd
May 15 08:56:07 ilcepoc500 oci-systemd-hook[43025]: systemdhook <debug>: 92140d272e14: Skipping as container command is /go/bin/all-in-one-linux, not init or systemd
May 15 08:56:18 ilcepoc500 oci-umount[44315]: umounthook <debug>: prestart container_id:12d638f87c0d rootfs:/storage/docker/overlay2/ab7502908ea8a939e9ea7379f9715e40b563717404fc5c2ee923062e67520f15/merged
May 15 08:56:21 ilcepoc500 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.
May 15 08:56:21 ilcepoc500 systemd[1]: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

I followed some linked of Github and SO but no luck so far any hints are appreciated
Below are the things that I have tried:

1. deleted `/var/log/docker`, reloaded docker-daemon and tried restarting docker, didn't work.
2. Create a file named `override.conf` inside the dir `/etc/systemd/system/containerd.service.d` and tried restarting the docker service didnt work.

Comment: Just a bump, I'm experiencing the same issue. Have not found a solution yet, it seems like re-installing the OS is the easiest way to solve this for me right now. Also tried [the instructions to completely remove docker](https://askubuntu.com/a/1021506) and re-install it. Neither did that resolve the issue.